# Proving compactness of a subset

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

Let $I = [a, b]$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. We consider $C(I)$ with the maximum norm and define a subset of $C(I)$

$$M_c=\left\{f \in C^1(I): \int_a^b\vert f(x) \vert ^2dx + \int_a^b\vert f'(x) \vert ^2dx \leq c \right\}.$$

The goal is to show $\bar{M_c}$ is compact in $C(I)$.

My idea is to show that $M_c$ is relatively compact using Arzela-Ascoli lemma. In order to do that I need to show $M_c$ is bounded and equicontinuous. Unfortunately, I have no idea of how to show the latter fact. 
I would appreciate any help to solve my problem.

Comment: $$f(y) - f(x) = \int_x^y f'(t)\,dt = \int_a^b \chi_{[x,y]}(t) f'(t)\,dt$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that the family is equicontinuous you can just note that all $f\in M_c$ are lipschitz of (common) constant $\frac{c}{b-a}$ (having the first derivative absolutely bounded by construction)

Comment: The family isn't equilipschitz, it's equi-$\frac{1}{2}$-Hölder, though.

Comment: I'm wrong thinking it's also equilipschitz? The derivatives are squared equibounded, so they are absolutely bounded by a common constant. In case correct me. Actually I was wrong about the lipschitz constant, not taking the square root.

Comment: The integral of the square of the derivative is uniformly bounded. That doesn't mean that the derivatives are pointwise uniformly bounded on $M_c$. Consider $g_n(x) = \sqrt{n\max\{0, 1-nx\}}$ on $[0,1]$ and $f_n(x) = \int_0^x g_n(t)\,dt$. Then $g_n(0) = f_n'(0) = \sqrt{n}$ is unbounded, but $\int_0^1 g_n(x)^2\,dx = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.

Comment: I feel so stupid not thinking the functions could have peaks. Sorry for your time but thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Supose that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a $f_n\in M_c$ such that 
$$
\|f_n\|_{\infty}>n.
$$
Then there is a sufficiently large $n_0$ such that
$$
\int_{a}^{b}|f_n(x)|^2{\rm d} x
+
\int_{a}^{b}|f_n^{\prime}(x)|^2{\rm d} x
>c
$$
But this is absurd. We can only conclude that $M_c$ is limited, *i.e.* here is a $L>0$ such that $\|f\|_\infty<L$. Use this to show that, for all $x_0\in [a,b]$ fixed, 
$$
|f^\prime(x_0)|<L,\quad \forall f\in M_c
$$
Now use the idea given by Daniel Fischer, *i.e.* $f(y) - f(x) = \int_x^y f'(t)\,dt = \int_a^b \chi_{[x,y]}(t) f'(t)\,dt $ to proof 
$$
|f(y)-f(x)|\leq L\cdot |y-x|, \quad \forall f\in M_c, \quad \forall x,y\in [a,b]
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does $\chi _{[x, y]}$ stands for??

Comment: "Use this to show that" sorry I can't follow, use what to show? "The integral of the square of the derivative is uniformly bounded. That doesn't mean that the derivatives are pointwise uniformly bounded." So I don't know how to get the absolute value of $f'(x_{0})$ is less than $L$ for all $x_{0}$